# ejabberd mod_hello_world.erl is giving undefined parse transform 'lager_transform' error

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have put mod_hello_world.erl in ejabberd-16.02/include folder and trying to compile it using erlang shell.
Code in mod_hello_world.erl is

```
-module(mod_hello_world).

-behaviour(gen_mod).

%% Required by ?INFO_MSG macros
-include("logger.hrl").

%% gen_mod API callbacks
-export([start/2, stop/1]).

start(_Host, _Opts) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Hello, ejabberd world!", []),
    ok.

stop(_Host) ->
    ?INFO_MSG("Bye bye, ejabberd world!", []),
    ok.
```

When i am trying to compile on erlang shell like

13> c(mod_hello_world).

it is giving me error :- mod_hello_world.erl: undefined parse transform 'lager_transform'
error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you do not have lager dependency available. You need to have lager beam file available in your Erlang path (-pa option).